# Eliminate central substring from string with regex in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am defining a function in Python3 to manipulate a string with regular expressions.

I have problems finding the regular expression to extract part of the string. Consider the following input strings

```
str1 = "http://99.199.9.90:22/some/path/here/id_type_51549851/read"
str2 = "http://99.199.9.90:22/some/path/here/myid_31654/read"
```

For the above strings I would like to obtain as output the following strings:

```
output_str1: "http://99.199.9.90:22/some/path/here/id_type_/read"
output_str2: "http://99.199.9.90:22/some/path/here/myid_/read"
```

The final underscore in the output string is not mandatory.

To be more general it would be better to have it working also with the following string (if possible):

```
str3 =  "http://99.199.9.90:22/some/path/here/myid_alphaBeta/read"
```

outputting

```
"http://99.199.9.90:22/some/path/here/myid_/read"
```

Note that IP, port, paths are invented but the structure is like this.

I want to eliminate from the string part before `read` and after the last underscore considering the fact that there might be another underscore before.

So basically my output should contain the first part of the original string the final part and match a central part that is not part of the output. Putting it other words it should cut a central matching part of the string

I am starting from the regular expression outputting the whole string:

```
"(.+?)/some/path/here/(.+?)/read"
```

I tried something like `(.+?)/some/path/here/(.+?)_[.+?]/read`

but it did not work.

The function up now is this (the part to be :

```
def cutURL(str):
    res = str
    if (bool(re.search("(.+?)&someMatch=[0-9]+", str))):
        res = re.search("(.+?)&someMatch=[0-9]+", str).group()
    elif (bool(re.search("(.+?)/devices/(.+?)/read", str))):
        res = re.search("(.+?)/some/path/here/(.+?)/read", str)
    return res
```

Comment: inside square brackets `[.+?]` the characters are interpreted _literal_ - not with theire usual (one or more but lazy anythings)

Comment: Try `re.sub(r'(/some/path/here/[^/]*_)[^/_]*(/read)', r'\1\2', s)`, see https://regex101.com/r/VBzHuS/1

Comment: Then how to escape them?

Comment: Thanks it works. Is `r` saying copy all the substring before? Could you exaplain a little further the meaning of `[^/]*_)[^/_]*` (maybe in an answer)?

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
str2 = "http://99.199.9.90:22/some/path/here/myid_31654/read"
str2 = re.sub("myid_[0-9]+","myid_",str2)
```

For documentation of the `sub` method and more applications refer to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/regex.html#search-and-replace)

Answer (score 0):

From the examples above, you could substitute

```
_\w+/read$
```

with

```
_/read
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/Uv39t3/2/).